How to encode tuples when using useSingleContractMultipleData
I'm getting an error:

Error: invalid tuple value (argument="tuple", value="0x0000000000000000000000006c5ea89943ecf173823768c3272a15a80d49aadd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",

when trying to call useSingleContractMultipleData from uniswaps redux multicall
I'm trying to call it like so:
function encodeTuple(assetKey: { assetAddress: string; id: string; assetType: number }): string {
  return defaultAbiCoder.encode(
    // ABI type for the tuple
    ['tuple(address assetAddress, uint256 id, uint8 assetType)'],
    // Values for the tuple
    [assetKey]
  )
}

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unused-modules
export function useRPCAvailbleAccountBalanceV2LP(accountHash?: string) {
  const trackedTokenPairs = useTrackedTokenPairs()
  const tokenPairsWithLiquidityTokens = useMemo(
    () => trackedTokenPairs.map((tokens) => ({ liquidityToken: toV2LiquidityToken(tokens), tokens })),
    [trackedTokenPairs]
  )

  const contractParams = accountHash
    ? tokenPairsWithLiquidityTokens.map((x) => [
        accountHash, // First parameter: accountId
        //Note: these may need to be abi encoded
        encodeTuple({
          assetAddress: x.liquidityToken.address,
          id: '0',
          assetType: 1,
        }),
      ])
    : []

  const assetManager = useAssetManager()
  const results = useSingleContractMultipleData(assetManager, 'getAvailableBalanceByAccount', contractParams)

//...

I'm guessing the encoding for the tuple is wrong:
this is my abi fragment for the call im trying to use:
"type": "function",
"name": "getAvailableBalanceByAccount",
"inputs": [
  {
    "name": "accountId",
    "type": "bytes32",
    "internalType": "bytes32"
  },
  {
    "name": "assetKey",
    "type": "tuple",
    "internalType": "struct AssetKey",
    "components": [
      {
        "name": "assetAddress",
        "type": "address",
        "internalType": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "uint256",
        "internalType": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "assetType",
        "type": "uint8",
        "internalType": "enum AssetType"
      }
    ]
  }
]


Hmm it was alot simpler than I thought.
I don't need to manually encode the tuple, I thought I did because the the method didnt accept objects.  Instead i just need to pass the parameters as a nested array:
  const contractParams = accountHash
    ? tokenPairsWithLiquidityTokens.map((x) => [accountHash, [x.liquidityToken.address, '0', 1]])
    : []

